# Thermal strain of a rod between two walls

Tags: thermodynamics

[image]
I don't understand how thermal strain is \begin{gather*}\alpha\Delta T\\\end{gather*}
If the walls were not there, length of the rod would have been \begin{gather*}L_{o}(1+\alpha\Delta T)\\\end{gather*}
and now when the walls are brought closer to compress the rod, change in length would be\begin{gather*}L_{o}-L_{o}(1+\alpha\Delta T)\\=-L_{o}\alpha\Delta T\end{gather*}
and so strain should be change in length divided by length of rod before it is compressed, which is:
\begin{gather*}\frac{L_{o}\alpha\Delta T}{L_{o}(1+\alpha\Delta T)}\\\end{gather*}
Why is this reasoning wrong?

Comment: You divided it by the final length, not the initial length.

Comment: @ChetMiller: That's on purpose IMO. He considers free thermal expansion in a first (implicit) step, and then compresses the thermally expanded rod to its original length (which implements the constant length constraint). Hence, what you call the final length is actually the initial length of this second step.

Comment: @Oliver That would be the initial length for the compression step, not the thermal expansion step.

Comment: @ChetMiller: Yes, that's what I meant, and I suppose what Jeffrey meant. Hence the minus sign.

Comment: @oliver yeah that's what I meant. I skipped a minus a sign in the final equation because I felt the magnitude is what matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is perfectly right. The point is that all relations of (linear) elasticity theory (Hooke's Law) are only approximate anyway, i.e. they are only valid for relatively small deviations from equilibrium. For large deviations there is always a point where nonlinearity strikes, e.g. tensile failure.

In your example the deviations from equilibrium are only going to be small if
$$\alpha\Delta T \ll 1$$
So, when you calculate strain of the constrained state relative to the thermally expanded (but stressless, i.e. unconstrained) state, you correctly get
$$\epsilon=\frac{L_0\alpha\Delta T}{L_0(1+\alpha\Delta T)}=\frac{\alpha\Delta T}{1+\alpha\Delta T}$$
But due to
$$\alpha\Delta T \ll 1$$
you can approximate
$$\epsilon=\frac{\alpha\Delta T}{1+\alpha\Delta T}\approx\frac{\alpha\Delta T}{1}=\alpha\Delta T$$
These are the kinds of things, textbooks and excersices often silently omit and drive students crazy. On the other hand, if every implicit fact was always written out explicitly, books were two or three times as big, which would be a significant obstacle to motivation.

Comment: By approximating$1+\alpha\Delta T\\$ to be equal to 1, you have stated that final length of the rod after thermal expansion is approximately equal to initial length?

Comment: @JeffreyVintha: yes, but only up to zeroeth order. Since the numerator already contains $\Delta T$ to first order, this does not limit generality, the result will still be first order accurate. The "proper" way would be to do a Taylor expansion of the whole fraction, especially $1/(1+\alpha\Delta T)\approx 1-\alpha\Delta T$, but this would just add second order terms to the whole expression. So if you are only interested in a first order approximation, it is enough to just consider $1+\alpha\Delta T\approx 1$. Again, a common shortcut way of calculating, that confuses newbies. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the linear expansion coefficient is

$$ \alpha \equiv \frac{1}{L}\frac{d L}{d T} $$

The definition of linear strain is

$$ \epsilon \equiv \frac{d L}{L} $$

Both formulations apply for small deformations about equilibrium.

The true definition of thermal strain should be written as

$$ \left.\frac{d L}{L}\right|_{thermal} \equiv \epsilon_{thermal} \equiv \alpha\  dT $$

With an assumption of constant $\alpha$, we obtain

$$ \ln\left(\frac{L}{L_o}\right) = \alpha \Delta T$$

Expansion gives

$$\Delta L = L - L_o = L_o\left[\exp(\alpha \Delta T) - 1\right] $$

Using the assumptions of small deformations and constant $\alpha$, we can write this instead

$$ \frac{\Delta L}{L_o} \approx \alpha \Delta T$$

Here is a plot of the two functions for $\Delta L/L_o$ with $\alpha = 0.3$. The green curve is the exponential and the blue line is the small deformation approximation.

[image: thermal strain plot]

In summary, the statement in the book should include the restriction that it applies only for small deformations (e.g. $\Delta L / L_o << 20$%).

Your approach also suffers from the same need. You cannot simply use the $\Delta$ form for length change to expand and recompress a rod unless you state that you are doing the expansion + compression process over small deformations (so that the infinitesimal derivative becomes a finite but small difference).